# Change initial view before viewDidLoad Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I work with Xcode Swift 7 and 2.
I want to know how to execute an action before viewDidLoad my initial view.
In fact I would like to change the initial view based on a parameter (if I am logged in or not) ...
Should we do it in the AppDelegate?
Thank you

Comment: you can add your code into `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in `AppDelegate`

Comment: And to change the initial view? I can not seem to change with the id of the controller ... It is in the StorageId need to identifier ?

Comment: So you want to initiate specific view from appdelegate?

Comment: Yes you need identifier then.and correct your question title.

Comment: but I can not ... He does not recognize my id ...

Comment: What code you are trying?

Comment: self.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("{MyId}") as? UIViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can initiate specific viewController from appdelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourID")

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Assign your storyboard ID this way:

Click on your storyboard then go to Identity Inspector at right side and give a storyboard id as shown in below image:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but he return "NSExeption, no controller with the identifier "MyId" "

Comment: yes because you are giving incorrect identifier to storyboard.

Comment: it is in the field need to StoryboardId ID? then check the checkbox below?

Comment: Don't check the checkbox ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let mainStorybord : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        
    Bool isAlreadyLogin =  <...code for to check for already logged in or not...>
        if  isAlreadyLogin
        {
    var homeVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("<homeVC>") as! UIViewController
    // HERE <homeVC> will be your identifier  for your sugue in storyboard for initial view after login.
            let nav : UINavigationController =  UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVc)
            self.window?.rootViewController = nav
        }
        else
        {
    var loginVC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("<loginVC>") as! UIViewController
    // HERE <loginVC> will be your identifier  for your sugue in storyboard for login view

            let nav : NavigationViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginVC)
            self.window?.rootViewController = nav
        }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```